# Is this continuity proof valid?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable and:

$$g(x, 1) = 4$$

$$g(0, y) = 4$$

$$g(x, x + 1) = x^2 + 4.$$

$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{g(x, y) - 4}{\sqrt{x^{2} + (y - 1)^{2}}} & (x, y) \neq (0, 1) \\
      0 & (x, y) = (0, 1)
   \end{cases}
$$

I have to prove $f$ is continuous. Now, I know that if $g$ is differentiable then it is continuous, then:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)} g(x, y) = g(0,1) = 4$$
So in

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)} \frac{g(x, y) - 4}{\sqrt{x^2 + (y - 1)^2}}$$
Is it valid to say that as I distribute the limit I get 0 because:
$$ \frac{0}{\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)} \sqrt{x^2 + (y - 1)^2}}$$ is $0$?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT valid, since both the numerator and the denominator converge to $0$ and hence you get a $\frac 00$ problem. If your method worked, then you would end up with the conclusion that the derivative of every uni-variate function is $0$, which is clearly not true.

But you can slightly modify your argument. Indeed, since $g$ is differentiable, we know that 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)}\frac{g(x,y)-g(0,1)-\partial g/\partial x|_{(0,1)}x-\partial g/\partial y|_{(0,1)}(y-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}=0.$$
Since $\partial g/\partial x|_{(0,1)}=\partial g/\partial y|_{(0,1)}=0$ (using the condition that $g(0,y)=g(x,1)=4$) and $g(0,1)=4$, we conclude that the limit of interest is equal to $0$, which is the same as $f(0,1)$, proving the continuity.